# How are javascript variables referenced?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently studying for a technical interview and I'm just going through the leetcode grind. I came across a question that is apparently asked pretty frequently by the company I'm about to interview at so I attempted it. I couldn't quite get it so I looked to the solution and came across this solution.

```
var merge = function(intervals) {
    if(!intervals.length) return intervals;
    intervals = intervals.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0])
    
    let prev = intervals[0];
    let res = [prev];
    
    for(let curr of intervals){
        if(curr[0] <= prev[1]){
            prev[1] = Math.max(prev[1], curr[1]);
        } else {
            res.push(curr);
            prev = curr;
        }
    }
    
    return res;
};
```

on line 5, res is set to equal [prev], which in this case is [1,3] so

```
res = [[1,3]]
```

for now.

Then as the code progresses, notice how the value of prev is updated. I thought this was weird since res is never updated at all, but by updating the value of prev, the prev inside res is also updated. My question is:

How does updating the value of prev update the value of the prev that's inside res? I thought I was going crazy so I tested it and this solution worked. I thought that once the prev inside res has been assigned, it would be immutable? Am I missing something here?

Comment: [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) and also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Comment: "*How are variables referenced?*" is the wrong question, or at least, demonstrates your misconception. There are no references to variables in JavaScript. What you might want to ask is "*How are **values** referenced?*"

Comment: An aside... these nonsense interview code samples give me a headache.  :-)  I get that this is just some simple data manipulation sample, but do you ever wish they'd do something more real?  And, the mix of `var` and `let` drives me nuts, hahaha.

Comment: @Bergi ya I wasn't really sure how to phrase this question so I just kind of typed out what I felt would be most correct and hoped for the best.


Brad I agree with you but I'm going to assume it's because they don't know what team you'll be working on when you apply so they just give you data structures/algorithms to see if you're up to snuff. This is for an internship position.

just a random thought but SO gets a really bad rep for being dismissive of questions but I don't think I've really run into a problem like that here before, so thank you all for the insight!

Comment: @Brad - It's like deciding whether someone can be a doctor by asking them to pass a sewing test. It only indicates something useful if they *can't* do it, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let prev = intervals[0];
let res = [prev];
```

At this point, `res[0]`, `prev`, and `intervals[0]` all have the same value.

```
console.log(prev === res[0]); // true
console.log(prev === intervals[0]); // true
console.log(res[0] === intervals[0]); // true
```

If this value were referencing an object, then they all point at the object.  If you were to reassign `prev`, that does *not* modify `res[0]`, nor `intervals[0]`.

```
prev = 'something else';
console.log(prev === res[0]); // FALSE
console.log(prev === intervals[0]); // FALSE
console.log(res[0] === intervals[0]); // true
```

> How does updating the value of prev update the value of the prev that's inside res?

You can see by this example that updating the value of `prev` does not actually update the value of `res[0]`.

However, updating the value of `prev[1]` is actually updating the value of index `1` of the object/array that `prev` references.  In other words, you're not changing `prev` by setting `prev[1] =`... you're changing `prev[1]`, which is the same as `res[0][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `prev`'s [reference](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference) is being pointed by `res` when you do `res=[prev]`, basically the address where the actual `prev` array is stored is pointed, as the prev updates, it also show changes in res.

Comment: JavaScript is always pass-by-value

Comment: pass-by-value/pass-by-reference doesn't apply here at all, since there's no function call

Comment: Maybe using the term "passed" leads to a misunderstanding. It's more like "points to", or "is a".

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to you because you're assuming that a new copy of `prev` is being created when you do `res = [prev]`.
Instead, try to think of it this way: an array gets created which internally points to the memory address of the data that `prev` contains. Whenever data in that memory address changes, it will be updated everywhere that address was used.
I would read up about reference types vs primitive types.